# Segmenting/Differentiating between two objects of the same color but overlapped

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

So I have a situation where I am trying to segment two markers of the same color but they are overlapping. What I am ending up with is one blob and not two blobs. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Here is the picture:
[image]

Is there anyway to differentiate between those two green markers so that they appear as two different objects on my segmented image?

Here is the code for the segmentation:
    [bw,maskedRGBImage] = createMask(RGB_image);

```
r = maskedRGBImage(:,:,1); %red layer
g = maskedRGBImage(:,:,2); %green layer
b = maskedRGBImage(:,:,3); %blue layer

justGreen = g - r/2-b/2;

bw = justGreen>10; %anything above 50 in green goes in bw


bw2 = imfill(bw,'holes'); %fill the holes in the image bw and save it in bw

bw3 = bwlabel(bw2,8); %label the differnet parts of the image wid an integer value

bw3 = imfill(bw3,'holes');


s = regionprops(bw3,{'centroid','area','Perimeter','EquivDiameter'}); %using 

%%%%%%Create Mask code%%%%%%%%
% Convert RGB image to chosen color space
I = rgb2ycbcr(RGB);

% Define thresholds for channel 1 based on histogram settings
channel1Min = 0.000;
channel1Max = 188.000;

% Define thresholds for channel 2 based on histogram settings
channel2Min = 0.000;
channel2Max = 132.000;

% Define thresholds for channel 3 based on histogram settings
channel3Min = 0.000;
channel3Max = 123.000;

% Create mask based on chosen histogram thresholds
BW = (I(:,:,1) >= channel1Min ) & (I(:,:,1) <= channel1Max) & ...
(I(:,:,2) >= channel2Min ) & (I(:,:,2) <= channel2Max) & ...
(I(:,:,3) >= channel3Min ) & (I(:,:,3) <= channel3Max);

% Initialize output masked image based on input image.
maskedRGBImage = RGB;

% Set background pixels where BW is false to zero.
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume something about the shape of the markers, elliptical, for example, then you can use the edge pixels and fit them using RANSAC to an ellipse.  Once you have a good fit, you can remove that ellipse and repeat until you have no significat marker pixels left.